# py2exe single executable file doesn't work

Tags: python, error-handling, py2exe

I'm trying to generate a single executable file with py2exe, without dependencies. With a standard setup.py file and all dependencies the exe works but when I try to modify setup.py to generate a single exe, the .exe file is generated but when I click it doesn't work.
This is the code of my python script:

```
# ======== Select a directory:

import Tkinter, tkFileDialog

root = Tkinter.Tk()
dirname = tkFileDialog.askdirectory(parent=root,initialdir="/",title='Please  select a directory')
if len(dirname ) > 0:
    print "You chose %s" % dirname 


# ======== Select a file for opening:
import Tkinter,tkFileDialog
import sys
import ntpath
import os

root = Tkinter.Tk()
file = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title='Choose a file')
if file != None:
    reader = file
    print type(str(reader.name))
    output_name= os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(str(reader.name)))[0]
    writer = open(output_name+'_Elaborata.txt','w')


    count = 1
    countbis = 0
    index = 0
    c = 0
    listaindex = []
    firstline = 1
    flag = False

    a = ''.join([chr(n) for n in range(256)])
    b = ''.join([n for n in a if ord(n) >= 32 and ord(n) <= 126])
    c = ''.join([n for n in a if ord(n) < 32 or ord(n) > 126])
    #print a
    arraychar = []

    #for n in range(256):
        #if(n >= 32 and n <= 126):
        #   print n, chr(n)
        #else:
            #arraychar.append(chr(n))

    result = "".join([(" " if n in c else n) for n in a if n not in c])

    #print a
    #print result

    #print arraychar
    listaelem=[]


    with reader as f:
        for _ in xrange(3):
            next(f)
        for line in f:
            if('-------' in line):
                continue
            if(line.strip() != ''):
                lista = line.split("|")
                if(len(lista) != 10):
                    pass
                    #print len(lista), line.strip()
                lista2 = []
                for elem in lista:
                    #Pulitura singola linea da caratteri speciali
                    result = "".join([("" if n in c else n) for n in elem.strip() if n not in c])
                    lista2.append(result.strip())
                if len(lista2) != 10:
                    #print line.strip()
                    pass
                string = ""
                for elem in lista2:
                    string += elem + "|"

                writer.write(string[:-1]+"\n")

    reader.close()
    writer.close()
```

Which setup.py could be correct to generate only one .exe file?

this is the setup.py:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
    options = {'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1}},
    windows = [{'script': "single.py"}],
    zipfile = None,
)
```

Comment: *when I click it doesn't work* - try running from the command-line.  I'm not saying it will work but you might get some error messages.

Comment: Also, which modifications did you do to `setup.py`?  Did you change anything else?

Comment: @cdarke I edited with setup.py